# How can i calculate the sum of the linq to sql group by result?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm beginner in `linq to sql`,write this query to calculate the group by my any data on database:

```
var query = (from p in behzad.STATUS
                         select p);

            var taskCounts = from worker in query.ToList()
                             group worker by worker.date into g
                             select g.Select(x => x.natije).ToArray();

            var result = taskCounts.ToArray();
```

when i debug my app,see result has my data,but i want calculate sum of the `x.natije` value's,my debug  is this:
[image]

i want calc `result[0].natije` sum to temp variable,for example this:

```
int temp=result[0].natije.sum
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. `natije` (whatever that is) is a string? You need to parse the strings to int and get the sum of that array?